# Sass with compass, paths working on a subdirectory

Tags: sass, compass-sass, zurb-foundation

I've just started with sass today and hit my first roadblock. I don't know how to use font-face inside my scss files. Here's what I've tried, inside my app.scss file:

```
//do I need this line? I have installed compass
@import "compass/css3";

@include font-face("myfont", font-files("myfont.eot", "myfont.woff", "myfont.ttf", "myfont.svg#myfont"));
```

And this is what I get rendered:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: "myfont";
   src: url('/assets/css/fonts/myfont.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/assets/css/fonts/myfont.woff') format('woff'), url('/assets/css/fonts/myfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/assets/css/fonts/myfont.svg#myfont') format('svg');
}
```

My config.rb file:

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "assets/css"
sass_dir = "assets/sass"
images_dir = "assets/img"
javascripts_dir = "assets/js"
fonts_dir = "assets/fonts"
```

And my right now my file structure is this www.mydomain.com/nameofmyproject and inside I have a folder called assets that contains css, sass, img, fonts, js folders

EDIT: Since this seems to be an issue with the paths I will edit my question. I'm working on a subdirectory here and firebug shows me a 404 for my font files, with the following url: www.mydomain.com/assets/css/fonts So it's both ignoring that I'm on a subdirectory and that I changed my fonts_dir to be inside assets and it goes to the default, inside the css directory.

Comment: Am I overlooking something here?  You've configured your fonts_dr to be "assets/fonts", but the actual path to your fonts directory from web root is "nameofmyproject/assets/js"?

Comment: the actual path of the fonts directory is  www.mydomain.com/nameofmyproject/assets/fonts and my config.rb file is inside  www.mydomain.com/nameofmyproject

Comment: I'm guessing, since I'm working on a subdirectory in my domain, that maybe my http_path is wrong? but changing it to "/projectname" won't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah my problem was a mix of issues, not restarting compass watch was not helping me debug the problem correctly and having a messed up installation was the problem at hand. I reinstalled and then started from scratch and it ended working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

When updating your config.rb file, You have to restart compass watch. Took me hours to figure that out. Hope this helps someone.